# I have just started c++ but I'm getting error in hackerRank for this code

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

this is the program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <conio.h> 
using namespace std;  

int main() {
    clrscr(); 
    cout<<"Hello, World!";
    getch();
}
```

fatal error: conio.h: No such file or directory  #include <conio.h>sdfs

Comment: why can't  I use conio.h header file?

Comment: `<conio.h>` is a C header, not C++. C++ compilers are not required to provide it. Similarly, `<stdio.h>` is a C header, and its functionalities are provided in C++ compiler implementations under `<cstdio>`, not its C header name.

Comment: If you are going to go for online judge sites, you should use a language you know: they are not learning resources.

Comment: `<conio.h>` is a very old MS-DOS header, found also on Windows for compatibility, but you definitely should stop using it as it is ancient and not portable.

Comment: @SankalpSrivastava Online judge sites like Hackerrank are designed for *experienced* programmers who want to answer random puzzle questions.  They are not designed for beginners, and as mentioned, not learning tools.  Hackerrank, leetcode, and any of those other sites assume you know the computer language you will be using well-enough to never have to ask basic questions about the language.  Too many beginners are drawn to these sites, only to waste their time -- time that could have been spent learning the C++ language properly.

Comment: @SankalpSrivastava As to your issue, were you given `Turbo C++` by someone, and thought that your code would work with an online compiler that uses modern C++?  If so, Turbo C++ is almost 30 years old, and uses a version of C++ where much of it is no longer relevant, and just doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: @SankalpSrivastava Because it's not a part of the C++ language.

Comment: You would do well to first learn C++ as it should be used and then you can train your problem solving skills using hackerrank (or leetcode or whatever). The C++ code you see on those sites is usually of very low quality. If you don't have books have a look at https://www.learncpp.com/ (it has some imperfections but is pretty good) and then read the https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines

Comment: One more thing, "C" is NOT "C++" they are different languages by now, with different ways of working.  Be aware most of the datastructures you're going to use are already implemented in the STL provided with C++ (like std::string,std::vector,std::array,std::list, std::stack). The moment you want to type new/delete try to find a different solution first (std::make_unique)

Comment: Also follow the instructions to the letter. It is very unlikely that the spec is to wait for a final useless entry.

Answer (score -5):

getch return a value
as follows

```
   #include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <conio.h> 
using namespace std;  

int main() {
    clrscr(); 
    cout<<"Hello, World!";
    char a = getch();
}
```

Comment: Assigning the return value is optional. In any case, the actual issue here is using a nonstandard include file.

Comment: Be aware too, that library i/o functions never use the `char` type for a single character. The function is `int getch(void);` or better `int _getch(void);` as `getch()` is deprecated. Probably neither is supported on coding sites, and any they never ask you to accept a final input. They define exactly what the input will be and what you must output.